# SXA 10.2 SiteManager not resolving correctly in Azure PaaS XP environment

Tags: sxa, azure, paas

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out why my Sites are resolving (or not resolving) the way they are.  A little background.  This is a migration from SC 9.1.1 to SC 10.2.  I've gone through the upgrade guide to upgrade our environments. Everything seemed to go smooth for the Standalone Single instance, but for our CD/CM environment I'm running into issues getting the site to correctly resolve according to the SXA site manager.

Here are the details.

App Service Environment:

- CM app service has the host domain: CM.sitedomain.com, preview.sitedomain.com
- CD app service has the host domain: CD.sitedomain.com, CD2.sitedomain.com as well as [www.sitedomain.com](http://www.sitedomain.com) and sitedomain.com

SXA Site entries in the Site grouping for the tenant are as follows:

**MainSite**

- site name: main_site_com
- valid for environment: *
- target hostname: [www.sitedomain.com](http://www.sitedomain.com)
- hostname: www.sitedomain.com|sitedomain.com|cd.sitedomain.com|cd2.sitedomain.com
- virtual folder: /
- start item: mainsite/home
- database: web

**Preview**

- site name: preview_site_com
- valid for environment: *
- target hostname: preview.sitedomain.com
- hostname: preview.sitedomain.com
- virtual folder: /
- start item: mainsite/home
- database: master

In SXA Site manager the order is as follows:

- shell
- login
- admin
- service
- modules_shell
- modules_website
- main_site_com
- preview_site_com
- website

No conflicts in site manager!

So here are the scenarios.  Let's start with Preview_site_com first

as I have it above, when I hit preview.sitedomain.com it is pointed to the CM server, but it is loading the main_site_com which is pointed to the web database when I check the sxa_site entry in the cookies.  If I move preview_site_com before main_site_com, it seems to work correctly and loads the site with the sxa_site entry showing preview_site_com

when I try to hit cd.sitedomain.com or cd2.sitedomain.com which is pointed at the CD app service, I always get sxa_site "website" in the cookie which is the default site with the girl with the phone.  It's like it doesn't even try to resolve.  I've even removed the target hostname from the main_site_com entry or replaced it with cd or cd2 to no avail.

This configuration is working in our production 9.1.1 environment, so I'm not sure why this new 10.2 environment is resolving weirdly.

Update:
On the CD app service, I can hit an aspx file directly with the CD or cd2 subdomains.  It seems like Sitecore is not processing the request?

Comment: Do you have any load balancer or some proxy? Does it pass the original hostname in host header?

Comment: Sounds like sites setup correctly but your app service binding might be missing, therefore always showing default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings

Comment: the custom domains with SNI bindings are there for both the CD and CM.  I'll need to check with my azure host to see if there is anything that's different from our current production causing issues.

Comment: Seems like the issue was caused by something that didn't update during the upgrade process from 9.1.1 to 10.2.  As far as the sxa_site cookie not correctly reflecting the correct loaded site, that has been reported as a bug by Sitecore after I opened a support case with them.